# Sqlmap dumping all tables without data

Tags: sqlmap

Is it possible to see all columns of all tables of a database without the data using sqlmap

I don't want to use -D database -T table manually for all the tables

Comment: It depends on what DBMS the target is using.

Answer (score 1):

The following queries can be used to retrieve (MySQL):

the list of all tables: `SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables` 
the list of all columns: `SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns`

Comment: Is there any other method to get them organised ? I mean like a table containing the columns names under their table

Comment: SELECT 1,concat(table_name,':', column_name),3,4 FROM information_schema.columns

Answer (score 0):

[Edit]

Please see the SQLmap `--schema` option.

> **Enumerate database management system schema**
>
> Switches: `--schema` and `--exclude-sysdbs`
>
> User can retrieve a DBMS schema by using this switch. Schema listing
>   will contain all databases, tables and columns, together with their
>   respective types. In combination with `--exclude-sysdbs` only part of
>   the schema containing non-system databases will be retrieved and
>   shown.

[SQLmap usage](https://github.com/sqlmapproject/sqlmap/wiki/Usage)

Comment: you need to specify what table to get the columns from, which is what the OP wants to avoid

Comment: Alright. Then `--schema` sounds like what the OP is after.

Comment: Can you confirm this and edit your answer with the correction and evidence?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
-D database --columns
```

No need to use the -T flag. Sqlmap will automatically get all columns of all tables.

Answer (score -1):

If the database MySQL, you can see the all tables in database:

`SELECT table_name FROM  information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema=database()`

You can find more important columns with this command. After that find the columns:

`SELECT column_name FROM information.schema_columns WHERE table_name='tablename'`

Comment: The OP asked for a sqlmap-specific answer; furthermore you should denote this is MySQL-specific.